# A bead is threaded on a frictionless vertical wire loop of radius R

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, rotational-dynamics

The question is the very last sentence at the end of this post. In this post, I'll demonstrate how I reach to a contradiction(the conditions mentioned in conjecture 1 should be satisfied by all stationary points in the phase space but I've derived some stationary points that do not satisfy the conditions. So I wonder: How can resolve this contradiction?).
[image]A bead is threaded on a friction-less vertical wire loop of radius $R$. The loop is spinning w.r.t. a fixed axis shown in the figure at a constant angular speed $\omega$. The Lagrangian is given by

$$L=\frac{1}{2}\dot\theta^2R^2+\frac{1}{2}R^2\sin^2\theta\omega^2+gR(\cos\theta-1)$$, where $\theta$ is defined in the figure(the arrow near the character $\theta$ indicates the direction in which it increases).

The equation of motion:

$$\ddot\theta=\sin\theta\cos\theta\omega^2-\frac gR\sin\theta$$

Next let's find out the stationary points in the phase space(A space with two degrees of freedom in the values of $\theta$ and $\dot \theta$. In addition, stationary points are points in the space which if we set as the initial condition would make the bead stay at where it is initially. e.g. ($\theta=0$, $\dot\theta=0$)): $$\ddot\theta=0\implies\sin\theta\left(\cos\theta\omega^2-\frac gR\right)=0\implies\sin\theta=0 \\ \text{and/or},\\ \cos\theta=\frac g{R\omega^2}$$

Hence, any stationary point should satisfy at least one of these conditions(*conjecture 1*). But here comes a problem:

First, approximating the e.o.m. in the vicinity of $\theta=\frac{\pi}2$, we get:

$$\ddot{\bar\theta}+\omega^2\bar\theta=0$$

where $\bar\theta=\theta-(\frac{\pi}2-\frac{g}{R\omega^2})$. Therefore, $\frac{\pi}2-\frac g{\omega R^2}$ is a stationary point between $0$ and $\pi$. Approximating the e.o.m. around $\theta=\frac{3\pi}2$, we get a similar result: $\frac{3\pi}2-\frac g{R\omega^2}$ is a stationary point between $\pi$ and $2\pi$. Therefore, since the integral curves in the phase space are periodic with period $2\pi$, we see that $\frac {\pi}2-\frac g{\omega R^2}+n\pi, \forall n\in \mathbb Z$ are stationary. However, these points may not satisfy the conditions mentioned in *conjecture 1*. Maybe they always satisfy the conditions but I don't think it seems to be the case.

There seems to be a contradiction here. Can somebody please help me resolve it?

Comment: Do you have a question? I can't find a question mark... there seems to be some speculation at the end there. Are you asking for your speculation to be confirmed? Or what?

Comment: At the end I reach to a contradiction.

Comment: A contradiction is not a question. What would you like to achieve with your post?

Comment: A contradiction is expected to be resolved

Comment: When I say "I reach to a contradiction", I think that I was making it clear enough to you. I mentioned the word "contradiction". In this way I make clear of my question automatically.

Comment: No you do not make anything clear. I was trying to help you - the format of posts here expects you to ask a question. You insist that people have to read your mind. Clear communication only happens when the person receiving the information has understood it. I took the liberty of editing your post to add what I _think_ is your question.

Comment: I'm really not clear on what the question here is either. Finding $\theta$ should be a *Lagrangian-free* doodle.

Comment: The question is at the end

Comment: Of course you can't figure out the evolution of $\theta$ in time just by elementary geometry. You need to writ down the lagragian and figure the equation of motion for it. But again, here the focus is on resolving the contradiction I've reached. The question is the very last sentence.

Comment: By making the series expansion around $\pi/2$ (which is not a stationary point: $\sin \theta = 0$ for $\theta = n\pi$) you threw away a bunch of terms which make this point unstable. So of course you get a bogus result.